# Fire mages in modern war?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, warfare

Is there a place for these fire mages in modern war?

Abilities:

Range 50 meters.

*Base level*

- Flame thrower: The standard modern flame thrower.
- Fire ball: This type of fire ball shoots a 6 inch diameter ball of fire from the Mage who launched the fire ball.

*intermediate level*

- Fire jump : This launches Mages into the air, and they can also use it to slow their descent.
- Plasma blades: Creates short blades of plasma. The short blades of plasma are 6 inches to 1 foot.

*Master level*

- Lightning generation: Shoots a lightning bolt from the mage.
- Plasma shields. The plasma shields encircles the mage in plasma sphere shield. The Mage, however, has to be be standing in place.
- Explosive ball of heat: The explosive ball of heat is capable of destroying a large room, and the range is the Mage's line of sight.
- Heat vision: Standard heat vision, which allows the Mage to see clearly through smoke and fire.

Would these abilities be of any use on a modern battle field? If so, would it only apply to the master level or could the lower levels still be of use?

Remark: All of the Mages, whether the intermediate level, base level or master level, all have the ability to not just aim, but to aim accurately and well.

Comment: Range 50? 50 what? What is "intermediate level"/"master level"? Can you properly format the text?

Comment: It has been Corected

Comment: lack of formatting is still there, please fix it

Comment: The formatting of this question remains poor. You should give us more details about each of these spells. What is flamethrower's range? how hot is it? how long can a mage maintain it? How many spells can a mage cast in a day?

Comment: What's a "plasma shield"?: Will it stop 82mm mortars? 120mm rockets? 30mm cannon DU rounds? 5-inch rounds from a frigate? What's a "plasma blade"? Will it cut through tank armor? Lighter vehicles? Aircraft? Submarines? Cool names are nice, but without capabilities and limitations for each, your asking for opinions *based solely on the names*. I think a "plasma blade" can cut through four miles of seawater and fillet a submarine in a fraction of a second, but you might have something different in mind.

Comment: @user535733 depends how dose  82mm mortars and 122mm rockets 30 km cannon DU rounds survive 40,000° F

Comment: @L.Dutch is it better now?

Comment: I feel too much is still missing. What is a 'standard' flamethrower? One from the games, movies, real infantry or real tabks? What is burning from the fireball? What will stop it from just immediately stopping after throwing? What kind of plasma? There's also low temperature plasma, just like you have low temperature liquid or air. How much control do you have over the lightning? Won't it immediately ground in the mage? What is 'standard' heat vision? How does the explosive ball of heat work? Details that can make or break the idea of a fire mage.

Comment: VTC:OB. It's possible for us to explain how your mages could be used in one specific engagement where you've explained all of the details of the engagement (the disposition and nature of forces, logistical limitations, geography and climate, etc.). But asking how your mages could be used "universally" is like asking how a gun can be used "universally." It's almost easier to explain how they *can't* be used. Consequently, this question violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule and is opinion-based because it's impossible for any answer to be better or worse than any other.

Comment: It is so disappointing to see that such an interesting worldbuilding question is going to be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if the mages are carrying guns, then at the very least they can't be any worse than normal soldiers. A solder who can shoot fire as well as shoot ought to count for something.

Master level mages may not even need a gun, as they have many techniques at their disposal with a similar range.

In addition, if that plasma shield can stop bullets, it provides a huge advantage for the mage's allies. Even if it can't, the mage could cause a nearby explosion and cast plasma shield to protect their allies from debris.

Comment: " . . . at the very least they can't be any worse than normal soldiers." On a broader scale this depends on the time and cost of training (or finding) a mage compared to a normal soldier. Of course if training is free then a mage is indeed a normal soldier plus. But it might be more efficient to train ten riflemen instead of a single mage.

Answer (score 2):

**Fire mages: all time defense.**

Sometimes you are playing a sporting type game but one person is so overpowered compared to the rest of you the game gets silly.  You dont want to kick out a person like that because that seems mean.  You can level things out some by making the Olympian all time defense: on neither team, but tries to stop both teams from scoring.  If all time defender takes possession, it is handed off to whatever team did not have possession before.

That would be how fire mages would be - all time defense.  For one, getting burned sucks so no-one wants them on offense.  For two they always burn up their own uniforms (and underwear, and hair) so you cant tell what side they are on - just a bunch of naked bald mage people running around on fire (not that there is anything wrong with that!).  For three war is hell and less hellishness is welcome.

The firemages would work to settle things down generally - blocking shots, launching themselves into the air, lightning bolts and plasma shields where needed as needed.  They would be a huge boon if it were cold (fire makes you warm) and also for smokers especially if it was rainy.  Heat vision would help them find other fire mages to coordinate their defensive efforts and also see when soldier's smokes had gone out which would be more of an issue with stogies than ciggies.  I am thinking the plasma blade mages could help in the kitchen because imagine raw steak, cut thin with plasma blades.  You cant do that with regular red hot blades because they stick to the steak but plasma blades could do it and it would be delicious!

Dang I wish there was some way to do that in real life.  The steaks, not the naked fire mages though they would be ok too.  Maybe lasers?